# Filtering Rules based on Subsets in Association rule data mining

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-mining

Filtering Rules based on Subsets-
1)What is the support value for Leather Pouch -> Screen Guard ? Store the value in Variable support
2)What is the lift value for (Arm Band, Mobile Cover)->(Screen Guard) ? Store the value in variable lift. Round off to 2 decimal places
3)In how many scenarios do you see 2 items (dualtons) in the antecedent set ?Stor the value in the variable dualtons

```
Data = [['Power Bank', 'Screen Guard' , 'Travel Charger'],
     ['Screen Guard', 'Bluetooth Headset', 'Mobile Cover'],
     ['Screen Guard','Arm Band','Mobile Cover'],
     ['Power Bank','Screen Guard','Leather Pouch'],
     ['Bluetooth Headset', 'Power Bank' , 'Mobile Cover']]
    from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
    from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules
    from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
    import pandas as pd
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
    pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
    te = TransactionEncoder()
    te_ary =  te.fit(Data).transform(Data)
    dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)
    frequent_itemsets = apriori(dataFrame, min_support=0.1, use_colnames=True)
    association_rule =association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="confidence", min_threshold=0.7) 
    
    ###Start code here
    support = 
    lift = 
    dualtons =
```

Answer (score 0):

After executing the code, you can print the association_rule.

```
support = 0.2
lift = 1.250000
dualtons = 9
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVVRE.png)